# In playwright,how to wait for all instances of loading spinner to disappear?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test, e2e

The test is failing because the loader doesn't allow saving the form  but my methods isn't working.

I too have tried to use a function and Promise.all with waitForElementState('hidden'), but doesn't work. It's necessary to get all elements of this component (with $$, all() or another way) because the page is finding more than 2 elements (sometimes is 3 or more).

My methods:

function (called by `await waitForLoadersToDisappear(page)`), i've tried with page.$$ too:

```
async waitForLoadersToDisappear() {
  const loaders = await this.page.getByTestId('form-loader').all(); 

  await Promise.all(
    loaders.map(async (loader) => {
      await loader.waitForElementState('hidden');
    }),
  );
}
```

I too have tried this methods without functions:

`await expect(page.$$('.loader')).toBeHidden();`

`await expect(page.locator('div[class="loader"]')).toBeHidden();`

`await expect(page.getByTestId('form-loader').all()).toBeHidden();`

`const loader = page.$$('form-loader'); //tried with locator.all() too await loader.waitForElementState('hidden');`

Loader image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbzEW.png)

HTML element:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL9xT.png)

Maybe can i wait this ::before stop works?

Comment: A very good practical question!

Answer (score 4):

```
await expect(locator).toHaveCount(0);
```

[toHaveCount](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count) will wait until all loader instances disappear.

Reference:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/11988