# In playwright test cases failing in parallel mode whereas passes in serial model. The tests are running inside a docker container

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

**Background:** My project runs locally inside a docker container. I have a test file say `abc.spec.ts` that has 20 tests. I run my test in HEADLESS mode inside the docker container(I can run it in NON-HEADLESS mode also outside my docker container, I usually do it while I am writing tests). I run command `npm run playwright:test` configured in my `package.json` to run my tests.

**Each of the tests in `abc.spec.ts` file runs successfully when run in `default` mode **i.e.** tests run one after the other in sequential manner.** which is the default behaviour of playwright. However when I run test in parallel mode by adding the line `test.describe.configure({mode: "parallel"});` at the top scope of my test file then I am observing that some of the tests are failing.

I did run tests in this parallel mode for a number of times observed -

**1.** Random number of tests are failing with `Navigation failed because page crashed!` error.

**2.** Certain tests are failing around 90% of the time on an assertion statement that is looking for temporary visible text in UI. Like for example when you do some actions in UI and while that action is being performed the UI shows some temporary visible text like - "Loading..", "Please wait...", "Submitting data...". So the assertion like `await page.getByText("Loading...").toBeVisible()`, `await page.getByText("Please wait...").toBeVisible()`, `await page.getByText("Submitting data...").toBeVisible()` are failing most the time. Interestingly these are randomly passing sometimes as well.

**Note :** I know that tests should not depend on each other and should run independently in parallel mode. I have ensured that all my 20 tests are independent of each other and can be run in parallel. My docker has 8 CPUS, 8 GB RAM, 1 GB swap.

Can anyone please suggest me anything how to fix it. It is important for me to run my test successfully in `parallel` mode to save time as I have lot of test to run. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot count on an intermittent message like "Loading..." to always appear

It may or may not appear depending on the performance of the web server at a particular point for various reasons. hence you **cannot deterministically assert** it .

The only thing you can reliablely assert here is that *eventually* its not visible.

> Also remember, when you are running tests in parallel you are increasingly the
> load on the server as they all are hitting the server at the same
> time now.

The way I would handle these kind of elements is using an [web assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count) by verifying their eventual absence:

```
await expect(spinnerLocator).toHaveCount(0)
```

This way playwright would wait for these element count to reach to zero so it will work either ways if they appear or not hence which should work *every* single time.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76622997

Comment: thanks, I agree that webserver will get request in parallel now but how does that govern the appearing or not appearing of the loading text? Can you give me some example.

Also I don't see any point of the above assertion if it will pass anyways. It will not test my actual requirement of whether the loading text was visible at the time.

There is one more point 1 where I mentioned about the page crashes. Do you have any information on that pls?

Comment: It cannot be an "assertion", that's the whole point.

Comment: Regarding issue 1.,"Page crash" is an application level issue. Application should not crash on running tests in parallels.